# Take existing and plug in text before and after in excel

Tags: excel

I am given a list of hundreds of numbers.  How do I replace those values with text at the beginning of the value and something after the value?

My list looks like this:

```
101113171154
101113164428
100713142345
101113152751
```

I want my list to look like this:

```
'%101113171154%'
'%101113164428%'
'%100713142345%'
'%101113152751%'
```

How do I achieve my desired goal in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) is the Excel operator to paste strings together.  Suppose cell A1 contains 101113171154.  In cell B1, add

```
="'%"&A1&"%'"
```

Then B1 will be formatted as you want.  You can AutoFill down from B1 as long as your list is and Excel will update the `A1` to `A2`, `A3`, ... automatically.